# Unable to redirect a website by modifying etc/hosts file

Tags: google-chrome, dns, cache, hosts-file

I am trying to redirect a website by overriding its IP address in the hosts file. But it doesn't work. I have done the following so far:

1. Modified hosts file by mapping the IP address of `twitter.com` to `www.facebook.com`
2. Flushed the local DNS cache by `ipconfig /flushdns`
3. Flushed Chrome's internal DNS cache by going to `chrome://net-iternals/dns` and clicking "Flush DNS cache"
4. Restarted chrome and then went to `www.facebook.com`.

I hoped to see `twitter.com` as the hosts file has the IP of `twitter.com` for `www.facebook.com`. But it doesn't work. Chrome takes me to `facebook.com`.

Why is this? I have tried the same with Firefox and Internet Explorer as well. No luck. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect a website" ?  I wonder if those words mean what you think it means (you can't redirect a website using a hosts file, but you can change the IP address the browser connects to to try and get the web site.

Comment: I'm guessing that most browsers don't ask the OS to do much when it comes to name resolution, other than asking for the system dns server address, and then resolve the hostname query internally. DNS resolution time is a big component in the perceived performance of a browser, and name services often take as much as 2 minutes to time out, so the browser might be blocked by host configuration if the client relied on additional hostname lookup sources like NBT broadcast, WINS, or TNS or any other non-web service.

Comment: @davidgo yes i am trying to change the ip address the browser connects.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this using just a hosts file.  Almost all modern websites require a domain name to be provided once you have connected to the IP address to allow multiple websites to be hosted off a single IP address.

In order to do what you are trying to do you would need to redirect your traffic through a proxy server and modify the request.   You will also need to deal with HTTPS certificate issues because the twitter site won't have a certificate valid for the facebook.com subdomains.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have much knowledge about the https certificate. I had a class about DNS resolvers and was trying out this for fun. So, is there any way I can make my browser believe it is a valid certifcate and make it connect to twitter.com instead?

Comment: Also, I read that the etc/hosts file overrides any dns information provided by the nameservers. If there is a record in the hosts file for a hostname pointing to a specific IP, that is given first preference. So provided there is some way to deal with the certificates, is it possible to do what i am doing? I apologize if my question is not clear. As i said I am new to this concept and am kind of confused how it works! Thank you.

Comment: It is technically possible, but there is a steep learning curve before you are ready to try it.  You would need to MITM the connection (transparently proxy it), create your own CA and install your CA Cert in your browser, and then get the proxy server to generate a cert on the fly.

Comment: The hosts file does usually (but not in all setups) override the dns settings.  You should check that this is true in your setup by pinging the domain name and ensuring the desired target address appears.  (Also, note that hosts file requires an IP address at the start of the line and one or more domains - The first bit cant be a domain name.

Comment: It is possible for some very large sites that any request is handled the same way (ie it assumes the domain name, rather then acting on it).  If this is the case, you could just accept the incorrect cert and it should work - but this is very rarely the case - and if its not you will need to set up a transparent proxy to intercept the data - which is non-trivial.

Comment: I think I will learn about certificates and how to proxy and  try what you have told. Thanks a lot!